# Replace personal pronoun with previous person mentioned (noisy coref)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, coreference-resolution

I want to do a noisy resolution such that given a personal prounoun, that pronoun is replace by the previous(nearest) person.

For example:

`Alex is looking at buying a U.K. startup for $1 billion. He is very confident that this is going to happen. Sussan is also in the same situation. However, she has lost hope.`

the output is:

`Alex is looking at buying a U.K. startup for $1 billion. Alex is very confident that this is going to happen. Sussan is also in the same situation. However, Susan has lost hope.`

Another example,

`Peter is a friend of Gates. But Gates does not like him.`

In this case, the output would be :

`Peter is a friend of Gates. But Gates does not like Gates.`

Yes! This is super noisy.

Using spacy:
I have extracted the `Person` using NER, but how can I replace pronouns appropriately?

Code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
for ent in doc.ents:
  if ent.label_ == 'PERSON':
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a function that works for your two examples:

Consider using a larger model such as `en_core_web_lg` for more accurate tagging.

```
import spacy
from string import punctuation

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

def pronoun_coref(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    pronouns = [(tok, tok.i) for tok in doc if (tok.tag_ == "PRP")]
    names = [(ent.text, ent[0].i) for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ == 'PERSON']
    doc = [tok.text_with_ws for tok in doc]
    for p in pronouns:
        replace = max(filter(lambda x: x[1] < p[1], names),
                      key=lambda x: x[1], default=False)
        if replace:
            replace = replace[0]
            if doc[p[1] - 1] in punctuation:
                replace = ' ' + replace
            if doc[p[1] + 1] not in punctuation:
                replace = replace + ' '
            doc[p[1]] = replace
    doc = ''.join(doc)
    return doc
```

Answer (score 6):

There is specially dedicated [neuralcoref](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) library to resolve coreference. See the minimal reproducible example below:

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
doc = nlp(
'''Alex is looking at buying a U.K. startup for $1 billion. 
He is very confident that this is going to happen. 
Sussan is also in the same situation. 
However, she has lost hope.
Peter is a friend of Gates. But Gates does not like him.
          ''')

print(doc._.coref_resolved)

Alex is looking at buying a U.K. startup for $1 billion. 
Alex is very confident that this is going to happen. 
Sussan is also in the same situation. 
However, Sussan has lost hope.
Peter is a friend of Gates. But Gates does not like Peter.
```

Note, you may have some issues with `neuralcoref` if you pip install it, so it's better to build it from source, as I outlined it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678314/4317058)